# Is there a way to know from LLVM IR which calls are C/C++ standard library calls (printf, scanf, atan2)?

Tags: llvm

See this below llvm IR

```
%call = call double @atan2(double %19, double %21) #3  //library call
%21 = call float @llvm.fabs.f32(float %sub) //llvm intrinsic 
%22 = call float @foo(float %sub) //not intrinsic nor library
```

I can find that @llvm.fabs.f32 is an intrinsic call to llvm, foo is neither intrinsic nor library as I can get the parameter name and type. But how to know that atan2 is a c/c++ standard library call?

Comment: (atan2 is in the C standard library, not the C++ one.) IIRC the C standard library headers may legally #define atan2 __something_atan43, but I'm too lazy to look the rule up now. The consequence is that there is no definitive list that could be used to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

The getLibFunc of TargetLibraryInfo class (https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1TargetLibraryInfo.html#details) can be used for this purpose in LLVM. The TargetLibraryInfoWrapperPass needs to be performed first by adding it to the getAnalysisUsage function. Once the pass has been performed, getLibFunc() can be used by creating an object of type TargetLibraryInfo.